# JSON Parse Error (Windows 8)

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JsonArray.Parse(…) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951466/jsonarray-parse-error)

I am developing a manga information app for Windows 8 (in C#, XAML). I'm receiving information from a public web API (http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/) which I'll use in my app accordingly. I can receive the JSON string effectively but I cannot parse it correctly and I don't know what exactly is wrong with it. The error that comes up is "Invalid JSON string" but when I check on http://jsonlint.com/ it's a validated JSON String.

Everytime I run the code I get the following error:

Invalid character at position 0

Here is my code:

```
//Receive JSON String from MangaEden Website
var client = new HttpClient();
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/"));
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//
// Parse the JSON data
//
var manga = JsonArray.Parse(result);
```

Comment: Hate to ask this, but is the ` actually in your code?

Comment: @TravisJ other than getting parsing error they have nothing in common.

Comment: @L.B - It's the exact same parsing error, from doing the exact same thing, possibly from the same book.

Comment: @TravisJ I must be missing something but still don't see anything common other than this message `Invalid character at position 0`

Comment: Its a similar error but the solution for that Json Parsing error does not solve my issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your json is not an array it is an object containing an array, Try this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/"));

var obj = JObject.Parse(response);
var manga = obj["manga"] as JArray;
```

Comment: Windows 8 doesn't allow the use of System.Net.WebClient

Comment: @NamiKuro then use other classes to download your json(As i can see you can do it sucessfully:`*I can receive the JSON string effectively*`). The key point here is the last two lines.

Comment: hmm still didn't allow me to parse it. It threw up the exception `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0`

Comment: Also it's my first time messing with .NET so I'm not all that familiar with it yet.

Comment: Ah I see GetStringAsync works, I was converting it to a regular string instead of a Task<String>. Thanks for helping me L.B